# Do not allow bypassing the above settings via github api

Tags: github, github-api

Is it possible to set `Do not allow bypassing the above settings` to true with API? Can't find it in the docs https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.8/rest/branches/branch-protection and the server response returns no such property